# How to show very large tables in flutter app?

Tags: flutter

Can you guys recommend me a way to show very large tables (~15 columns and 50 rows) in flutter app? I tried to put table as image and make it zoomable and I tried with https://pub.dev/packages/extended_image and https://pub.dev/packages/pinch_zoom_image. They both work well for small tables and not for large tables.

Comment: Have a look at [How to create a horizontally scrolling table with fixed column in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942322/how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-table-with-fixed-column-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

The following stackoverflow question shows a way to display large table with horizontal and vertical scrolling. Have a look at the selected answer : [How to create a horizontally scrolling table with fixed column in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942322/how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-table-with-fixed-column-in-flutter)

If you need zoom in/out functions you can wrap your table with a GestureDetector.  onScaleStart and onScaleUpdate properties will allow you to set the zoom factor.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this dependency https://pub.dev/packages/json_table , which will also give you dynamic data based on your JSON and also you can scroll it both ways to view all the data.
And also other features can help you. If you use for large data this feature could help.

```
paginationRowCount: 4,
```

Also look at this https://pub.dev/packages/horizontal_data_table#-readme-tab- which could help you to manage scrollable data.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24718997)

Comment: @Regolith Please look at the overall health of the both dependencies. It is quite maintained. Please review first and then conclude.