# Flutter DataTable header pinning issue

Tags: flutter, datatable, flutter-layout

I could not find the flutter datatable header fixing process. How do I do this?
I could not find this feature on the fixed datatable with Flutter. I used the DataTable2 library. But I couldn't come to a conclusion with this library either.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58107974/how-to-implement-a-table-with-fixed-headers-in-flutter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SfDataGrid` for alternative.
https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_datagrid

for example :

```
List<Employee> employees = <Employee>[];

late EmployeeDataSource employeeDataSource;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  employees= getEmployees();
  employeeDataSource = EmployeeDataSource(employees: employees);
}

 List<Employee> getEmployees() {
  return[
  Employee(10001, 'James', 'Project Lead', 20000),
  Employee(10002, 'Kathryn', 'Manager', 30000),
  Employee(10003, 'Lara', 'Developer', 15000),
  Employee(10004, 'Michael', 'Designer', 15000),
  Employee(10005, 'Martin', 'Developer', 15000),
  Employee(10006, 'Newberry', 'Developer', 15000),
  Employee(10007, 'Balnc', 'Developer', 15000),
  Employee(10008, 'Perry', 'Developer', 15000),
  Employee(10009, 'Gable', 'Developer', 15000),
  Employee(10010, 'Grimes', 'Developer', 15000)
  ];
}
```

result :

[image: result SfDataGrid]