# Flutter: How to create a horizontally scrolling table with fixed first column?

Tags: flutter, datatable

I'm a new in Flutter. I need to fix first column in my table. I see this topic: [How to create a horizontally scrolling table with fixed column in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942322/how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-table-with-fixed-column-in-flutter), but I don't know how to apply answer to my code. I try to do this, but I see error. Code:

```
class DataTableWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  DataTableWidgetState createState() => DataTableWidgetState();
}

class DataTableWidgetState extends State<DataTableWidget> {
  bool ascending;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    ascending = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: SizedBox(
          width: width * 1.4,
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              buildDataTable(),
              Flexible(  //after I added flexible class, I see Errors
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      child: buildDataTable())),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildDataTable() => DataTable(
...
```

Comment: What do you want to make different from the answer? Maybe it could be easier if you just start with the code provided in the answer and start changing it.

Comment: In Answer uses other type of filling table. I try to change code in Answer, but there are many differences in the code. I use other method to add data into table